# how to maintain single datasource url and username

Tags: birt

i have small problem  in birt Tool,

I created around 10 reports , now i want to maintain single url and username for all data sourcees , Without touching each xml file

Advanced Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, it sounds like using a BIRT library could be the solution. 
To do this, create a new BIRT library from the "New" menu, and create your datasource inside the library (in the same way you create a datasource in a report). 
Save the library, then import it into each of your reports via the library view. By using the datasource from your library, you will only have to update it in one place. If the url or credentials need to change, just change them in the library and the changes will automatically be picked up in all reports that use that library. 
There is a thorough and very useful tutorial on BIRT libraries and templates here: 
[Birt libraries](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364376/Using-Eclipse-BIRT-Report-Libraries-and-Templates)

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a connection profile to manage the JDBC connection parameters in a single file :

- right click on datasource
- externalize to connection profile

http://www.birtreporting.com/BIRT%20Connection%20Profiles.pdf

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Birt_3.7_Migration_Guide#Connection_Profiles

if you also want to get them dynamically, see the following example:

http://jonnazario.blogspot.fr/2012/07/birt-37-dynamic-connection-profiles.html